# How to register/deregister/reregister API Controller at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-apicontroller

We are developing an application mainly depends on the customer configurations to compile and register a set of API Controllers. We are doing that in the Application start by providing our own implementation of IAssembliesResolver. That works fine with us.

Now we have a new requirement to Deregister and Register controllers while the application is running (Runtime) without restarting the application. As restarting the application or IIS which will take a long time.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: why overcomplicate things in this way? what the gain? I think it can be simply done by authorization and it would save you tons of debugging time.

Comment: Use dependency injection

Comment: @JackM, I don't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: Well, why register and deregister controllers ???? you can use authorisation and depending on which user, gain or refuse access. Easy to code, easy to test, easy to maintain

Comment: OK, First, the application will be installed into different customers where each customer has his own configurations. We are not allowed to share configurations. So it is not an option for us have all possibilities and use user permissions. Second, the configurations can be changed by the customer which force the application to regenerate the API controller code and do the complication. Here we need the functionality of Deregister and Reregister API controllers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IHttpControllerFactory`:

---

Controller Factory class:

```
public class MyHttpControllerFactory : IHttpControllerFactory
{
    private readonly InterfaceReader _reader;
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyHttpControllerFactory(InterfaceReader reader, HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _reader = reader;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IHttpController CreateController(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, string controllerName)
    {
        if (controllerName == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", controllerContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath));
        }

        // Change the line below to whatever suits your needs.
        var controller = _reader.CreateController(new MyImplementation());
        controllerContext.Controller = controller;
        controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(configuration, controllerName, controller.GetType());

        return controllerContext.Controller;
    }

    public void ReleaseController(IHttpController controller)
    {
        // You may want to be able to release the controller as well.
    }
}
```

And at global.asax register the custom controller factory:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private readonly InterfaceReader _reader = new InterfaceReader(); // this class is doing all staff with reflection to create controller class

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetService(typeof(IHttpControllerFactory), new MyHttpControllerFactory(_reader, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
    }
}
```

---

I prefer to use `IHttpControllerActivator` when using web api 2.0.

---

Controller Activator class:

```
public class MyServiceActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly InterfaceReader _reader;
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyServiceActivator(InterfaceReader reader, HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _reader = reader;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        // Change the line below to whatever suits your needs.
        var controller = _reader.CreateController(new MyImplementation());
        return controller;
    }
}
```

And in global.asax, register custom activator:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    // this class is doing all staff with reflection to create controller class
    private readonly InterfaceReader _reader = new InterfaceReader();

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new MyServiceActivator(_reader, config));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barr, This is exactly what I need. I create a small prototype to test the concept and it seems to be working as I expect.

Comment: What is InterfaceReader ?

Comment: Look at the comment